# Redis Snapshot-Configuration: How are multiple changes on the same key counted?

Tags: redis

in Redis you can configure the creation of snapshots, e.g. "save 60 10" would save the database after 60 seconds if at least 10 keys were changed.

If the SAME key was changed 10 times, would a snapshot be saved? Or does this refer to 10 unique/different keys that have to be changed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The documented config doesn't say anything about "if at least 10 keys were changed". It says the snapshot will happen if "the given number of write operations against the DB occurred". Simple commands like `SET` and `DEL` count as one write operation. More complicated commands like `HMSET` and `ZINTERSTORE` might count as more than one write operation depending on the number of values they affect. Nothing takes into account the number of unique keys that were written to since the last snapshot.